# Nginx and subdomains issue

Tags: nginx, subdomain

Nginx and subdomains issue

Hi,
Here's my configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  my_server.com www.my_server.com demo.my_server.com;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://123.456.789.10:8080/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why if I point the browser to: my_server.com or www.my_server.com 
everything's fine, but if I go to demo.my_server.com, firefox can't find the server at demo.my_server.com.

Hints?
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the issue is an inability to find the server at demo.my_server.com, then you almost certainly don't have demo.my_server.com in DNS. This can be checked by running

```
nslookup demo.my_server.com
```

on windows, or

```
dig A demo.my_server.com
```

on (Li|U)nix. To fix this, you'll need to add demo.my_server.com to DNS as an A record, with the same value as www.my_server.com.

Comment: You are right Cian, I have to add demo.my_server.com as an A record.